# AngularJS: conflict between ng-route and Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datetimepicker, angularjs-ng-route

I'm in the process of finishing up a calendar app and I want to use the datetimepicker to update events. 
What I'm using can be found here: http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/

heres an HTML example of how I'm using it:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="width:450px;">
    Selected Start Date: {{ event.start._i | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' }}
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="start" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#start" href="#start">
        <div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="event.start._i">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="cLabel">
        <datetimepicker data-ng-model="event.start._i" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#start' }"/>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

So what this is supposed to do is provide a dropdown that allows you to select the date and time (imagine that). The problem is the anchor tag needs the href="#" attribute in order for the dropdown to work. I don't really understand why it needs that I just know that it fails (as in it does nothing at all) if I take it out or change it. With the href left in theres a conflict with ng-route, meaning when you try to open the dropdown it instead routes you to a page that doesn't exist ( '#' ).

I've done a bunch of googling but only found one so far that seemed to match my problem. Their fix was to remove the # from the href, but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Does anyone have a suggestion for fixing this? Is there a way that I can force ng-route to play nice? or even disable routing for the specific event thats causing the mixup? Thank you in advance for any contribution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may have this problem....
I was able to solve this by using

```
.run(['$rootElement', function($rootElement){
  $rootElement.off('click');
}]);
```

Basically this disables the click interceptions that angular does. So the routing only works on intended targets.

Answer (score 0):

I found that appending the anchor to the URL did achieve the desired effect of switching the tbs while Angular routing was active.

For instance, with the bootstrap tabs code...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <li class="active"><a class="chat-btn" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Chat</a>
  </li>
  <li class="gameseetings-btn"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Game Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

e.g - for localhost:3000/#/play if I clicked those tab/anchor links with the #home and #menu1 anchor hrefs, Angular routing would intercept and then run through to the default "route not found" destination.

However pasting http://localhost:3000/#/play#menu1 into the URL bar got the tab to switch.

That said it also seems to reset my app in the process - it forces a page refresh on what is likely to be an Angular SPA (using ngRoute we are) but it might be useful to some to know this behaviour for other purposes - in short YMMV there might be a use for it ;-)

- EDIT *

I found a solution that doesn't involve turning off the click interception totally for Angular...

http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/angularjs/11580004.html

...notably this bit > *"Adding target="_self" works in Angular 1.0.1: Sign in with Facebook This feature is documented (docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location - search for '_self') If you're curious, look at the angular source (line 5365 @ v1.0.1). The click hijacking only happens if !elm.attr('target') is true."*

tried this and bingo - BootStrap tabs working while Angular routing in effect... props to the OP of that advice - other good options/suggestions there that might help other cases too.